# sublime text 2 - git plugin

Tags: git, sublimetext2

I bought and installed Sublime text 2 on windows 7
I also installed the Git plugin

Now, I added a file to the staging index and it worked ... git status also works ... git commit on the other hand doesn't:

This is what i get:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'me@me-PC.(none)')
```

I do not know how to fix this.

thanks,
Rares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type those commands in a git-cmd session or a git bash session.

Git needs to known the author and committer name and email.

As mentioned in [`kemayo/sublime-text-git` issue 246](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/issues/246#issuecomment-152734751):

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

If you have installed msysgit, you will find a git-cmd.bat or a shortcut to a git bash session, in which you will be able to type those `git config` commands.

*But*, you also need to make sure that the Git plugin known where your `HOME` is, `HOME` being not set by default by Windows.

Comment: well i am using git just fine ... using git bash .. only the commit from within Sublime Text 2 does not work ... the normal commit from git bash does work ...

Comment: @user2030809 then check HOME, if sublime2 doesn't know it, that would explain why it doesn't find the global config file.

Comment: @user2030809 or does the `git config` directly in your repo (local config)

Comment: if i do echo %HOME% in cmd i get => c:UsersAdmin

Comment: @user2030809 if `Admin` is your  Windows account, then it is ok, and you need to launch your Sublimie Text from that session. You need also to check if there is a `.gitconfig` in `C:\Users\Admin`. If not, type the `git config --global` commands mentioned in your question.

Comment: yeap ... that was it ... i edited the config file in the etc folder and put in the details :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

What did you set your email to?

> fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'me@me-PC.(none)')

According to the error msg the email is; **me@me-PC.**  And by the looks of it, the sublime plugin have problem with parsing an invalid email.

Double check your email with:

```
git config -l
```

Comment: no man ... when u install git u have to set name and email so it knows who u are ... git here was trying to find the email ... i use the standalone version of git just fine ... but inside Sublime Text 2, git it does not recognize the global config ... my git is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe

Comment: Does git work in cmd.exe?  if not add your git path to your environment variables.