# Integrate Sublime text 2 with git

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using Sublime editor and want to sync it with Github. Can we do it using some additional plugins or not ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

[sublime text 2 - git plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001319/sublime-text-2-git-plugin)

https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-git